# Unequally charged hanging pith balls

Tags: electricity, charge

I have done a problem which asks us to find the charge on two equally 'massed and charged' pith balls which are left hanging on a string with a certain length that repels each other and attains an equilibrium point making an angle (the string) with the vertical.

The problem was quite clear, what left me wondering was: Won't the angle be the same if the balls are unequally charged (but equally massed) ? Or does it deviate from the initial case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your product $|q_{1}||q_{2}|$ remains the same as in the case where you had the equally charged spheres, then yes, you will get the same value for the angle (provided the masses are equal). This is because the electrostatic force acts equally on both charged spheres.

Answer (score 1):

I've found an explanation. As Duncan said, as the sum of the charges stays equal the greatest product of two integers with a certain sum is half of the sum when (for example 5+5=10 and 5x5=25 is the greatest product. NOTE: Here the sum is always even as we take two equal charges 'q' initially).

Hence all other series yields a force lesser than the ideal case stated above (ie equal charges) and hence the angle will be always less than this case.

Thanks Duncan